# Correct answer erroneously deleted

Tags: discussion

In a recent [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12826/major-push-updgrade-postinstall-script-error-field-is-not-writeable), a proposed answer was deleted after the OP stated it didn't solve their problem. In the end, it turned out to be correct answer but a different answer received the credit.

How should this be handled? Should the original be undeleted and marked as the answer or does it fall into the "oops" category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was deleted by the author who wrote it, so I don't see there is anything exceptional that should be done here.

Bigger picture, though —  the author simply posted a terse answer without any supporting information about *why* the answer would work. So when the question author said "didn't work", it was taken at face value and deleted. If the author fleshed out their answer a bit with supporting information and further explanation, it would have been a better answer overall… and wouldn't likely have been interpreted incorrectly (and deleted) in the first place. *Teach a man to fish.*

I don't see an action item here.

Comment: hola Robert, long time no see

Answer (score 2):

I saw that and thought the same thing, but then I realized the answer wasn't technically correct as he said look at the postinstall class. The problem was actually in a class called by the postinstall class. It was headed in the right direction, though.

I think it is fine to leave as is.